# Cant setup react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am starting to learn react, and I want to integrate react router in a simple project. The code is:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var Router = require('react-router');
var Route = Router.Route;
var hashHistory = Router.hashHistory;
var IndexRoute = Router.IndexRoute;

var APP = require('./components/APP');
var Map = require('./components/Maps');
var Graph = require('./components/Graph');



var routes = (
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={APP}></Route>
    <Route path="maps" component={Maps}></Route>
    <Route path="graph" component={Graph}></Route>
  </Router>
)

ReactDOM.render(routes, document.getElementById('react-container'));
```

But I am getting the following error:
Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Thanks

Comment: Probably is the way you are importing / exporting your components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Router component is not the default export of the 'react-router' library. The `Router` object in your code is just a wrapper object containing the pieces of the 'react-router' library, including both the `Router` and `Route` components. So access the `Router` component the same way you're accessing the `Route` component:

```
var router = require('react-router');
var Router = router.Router;
var Route = router.Route;
```